# How to check if the button has on-click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how can I check if the button has on-click listener. My webpage has a button, but sometimes clicking the button has no effect.I am wondering if I can check if the click handler is attached.

I tried this, but it doesn't work..

```
$('#changeStatus').onClick()
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Are you attaching those listeners? Is this for an extension? Your own page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the listener was applied....

If the listener was set up on the event property, you can check the property:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.onclick = function(){ console.log("I was clicked"); }

if(input.onclick){
  console.log("There is a click event listener.");
} else {
  console.log("There is NO click event listener.");
}

if(input.onkeydown){
  console.log("There is a keydown event listener.");
} else {
  console.log("There is NO keydown event listener.");
}
```

```html
<input>
```

But, if the listener is registered using the modern DOM API of `.addEventListener()`, then no, there is no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
var hasOnClick = ($('#changeStatus').attr('onClick') !== undefined)
```